# Allow help() to work on partial function object

Tags: python, pydoc

I'm trying to make sure running `help()` at the Python 2.7 REPL displays the `__doc__` for a function that was wrapped with `functools.partial`.  Currently running `help()` on a `functools.partial` 'function' displays the `__doc__` of the `functools.partial` class, not my wrapped function's `__doc__`.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Consider the following callables:

```
def foo(a):
    """My function"""
    pass

partial_foo = functools.partial(foo, 2)
```

Running `help(foo)` will result in showing `foo.__doc__`.  However, running `help(partial_foo)` results in the `__doc__` of a [Partial object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial-objects).

My first approach was to use [functools.update_wrapper](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) which correctly replaces the partial object's `__doc__` with `foo.__doc__`.  However, this doesn't fix the 'problem' because of how [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html).

I've investigated the pydoc code, and the issue seems to be that `partial_foo` is actually a [Partial object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial-objects) not a typical function/callable, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483527/why-doesnt-functools-partial-return-a-real-function-and-how-to-create-one-that) for more information on that detail.

By default, pydoc will display the `__doc__` of the object type, not instance if the object it was passed is determined to be a class by [inspect.isclass](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass).  See the [render_doc function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py#l1504) for more information about the code itself.

So, in my scenario above pydoc is displaying the help of the type, `functools.partial` NOT the `__doc__` of my `functools.partial` instance.

Is there anyway to make alter my call to `help()` or `functools.partial` instance that's passed to `help()` so that it will display the `__doc__` of the instance, not type?

Comment: I don't think there is any way around this; there are no hooks we can grab here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pretty hacky way to do this.  I wrote the following function to override the `__builtins__.help` function:

```
def partialhelper(object=None):
    if isinstance(object, functools.partial):
        return pydoc.help(object.func)
    else:
        # Preserve the ability to go into interactive help if user calls
        # help() with no arguments.
        if object is None:
            return pydoc.help()
        else:
            return pydoc.help(object)
```

Then just replace it in the REPL with:

```
__builtins__.help = partialhelper
```

This works and doesn't seem to have any major downsides, yet.  However, there isn't a way with the above naive implementation to support still showing the `__doc__` of *some* `functools.partial` objects.  It's all or nothing, but could probably attach an attribute to the wrapped (original) function to indicate whether or not the original `__doc__` should be shown.  However, in my scenario I never want to do this.

Note the above does NOT work when using IPython and the [embed functionality](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython).  This is because IPython directly sets the shell's namespace with references to the 'real' `__builtin__`, see the [code](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L1121) and old [mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2001-April/014068.html) for information on why this is.

So, after some investigation there's another way to hack this into IPython.  We must override the `site._Helper` class, which is used by IPython to [explicitly setup the help system](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L1136).  The following code will do just that when called BEFORE `IPython.embed`:

```
import site
site._Helper.__call__ = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: partialhelper(*args, **kwargs)
```

Are there any other downsides I'm missing here?

Comment: It's also worth noting this will NOT work in IPython.  I'm sure there's a way around it, but IPython doesn't have `__builtins__.help` even though the `help()` function is available in the global namespace.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

how bout implementing your own?

```
def partial_foo(*args):
    """ some doc string """
    return foo(*((2)+args))
```

not a perfect answer but if you really want this i suspect this is the only way to do it

Comment: This will work, but not very well for my scenario.  I have a big list of functions that all need to have the same argument defaulted to something at runtime.  So, this would require a bunch of these wrapper functions.

Answer (score 0):

You identified the issue - partial functions aren't typical functions, and the dunder variables don't carry over.  This applies not just to `__doc__`, but also `__name__`, `__module__`, and more.  Not sure if this solution existed when the question was asked, but you can achieve this more elegantly ("elegantly" up to interpretation) by re-writing [`partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial) as a decorator factory.  Since decorators (& factories) do not automatically copy over dunder variables, you need to also use [`@wraps(func)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
def wrapped_partial(*args, **kwargs):
    def foo(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def bar(*fargs,**fkwargs):
            return func(*args, *fargs, **kwargs, **fkwargs)
        return bar
    return foo
```

Usage example:

```
@wrapped_partial(3)
def multiply_triple(x, y=1, z=0):
    """Multiplies three numbers"""
    return x * y * z

# Without decorator syntax: multiply_triple = wrapped_partial(3)(multiply_triple)
```

With output:

```
>>>print(multiply_triple())
0
>>>print(multiply_triple(3,z=3))
9
>>>help(multiply_triple)

help(multiply_triple)
Help on function multiply_triple in module __main__:

multiply_triple(x: int, y: int = 1, z: int = 0)
    Multiplies three numbers
```

---

**Thing that didn't work, but informative when using multiple decorators**

You might think, as I first did, that based upon the stacking syntax of decorators in [PEP-318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax), you could put the wrapping and the partial function definition in separate decorators, e.g.

```
def partial_func(*args, **kwargs):
    def foo(func):
        def bar(*fargs,**fkwargs):
            return func(*args, *fargs, **kwargs, **fkwargs)
        return bar
    return foo

def wrapped(f):
     @wraps(f)
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         return f(*args, **kwargs)
     return wrapper

@wrapped
@partial_func(z=3)
def multiply_triple(x, y=1, z=0):
    """Multiplies three numbers"""
    return x * y * z
```

In these cases (and in reverse order), the decorators are applied one at a time, and the `@partial_func` interrupts wrapping.  This means that if you are trying to use any decorator that you want to wrap, you need to rewrite the decorator in a factory where the decorator's return function is itself decorated by `@wraps(func)`.  If you are using multiple decorators, they all have to be turned into wrapped factories.

---

**Alternate method to have decorators "wrap"**
Since decorators are just functions, you can write a `copy_dunder_vars(obj1, obj2)` function that retruns `obj2` but with all the dunder variables from `obj1`.  Call as:

```
def foo()
    pass

foo = copy_dunder_vars(decorator(foo), foo)
```

This goes against the preferred syntax, but practicality beats purity.  I think "not forcing you to rewrite decorators that you're borrowing from elsewhere and leaving largely unchanged" fits into that category.  After all that wrapping, don't forget ribbon and a bow ;)

Comment: Why not just use the "roughly equivalent" implementation mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools%20wraps#functools.partial)? Decorating the function you want to partially apply at definition time defeats the purpose; you should just use a constant inside the function.

Comment: Good point. I guess OP's use case wouldn't use decorator syntax, and would more likely use it as `foo=wrapped_partial(args)(bar)`. Also, that example doesn't include copying over `__docs__`, `__name__`, &c.  You can add those in of course, but to make sure you get all the dunders (including those that may be added in future pythons), you may as well use `@wraps`

Comment: Not really. `wraps` copies the `__module__` and `__name__` from the function you pass in, to prevent all decorated functions to have the name of the decorator. In other words: what comes out of a decorator should "be" what goes in, but with changed behaviour. `partial` creates a new function, with a different number of arguments and a different name. So the `__name__` and `__module__` should not be of what goes in, but those of the variable it gets assigned to (the caller). If you really want to do that in your implementation of `partial` you could hack with `inspect` to get the calling frame.

Comment: There are probably use cases for both patterns, and OP's stance on `__name__` and `__module__` will remain a mystery.  I ended up on this question because my use cases called for wrapping all the dunders.  Though I would be grateful if you can point out cases when wrapping `__module__` and `__name__` can cause problems (`%autoreload?`).

Comment: To wit: Custom loss functions in Keras need to accept two arguments, `y_pred` and `y_true`.  However, a Generator's loss in a GAN depends on the Discriminator.  I wrote the functions `early_gen_loss()` and `late_gen_loss()` in `losses.py` to accept the two arguments Keras needs plus the Discriminator.  When I build the GAN, I use `wrapped_partial()` to pass the Discriminator.  I still want the function to be called `early_gan_loss()` and it should know it's from the `losses` module.  I suppose a factory function might also work, but I sometimes want to call the loss with all three arguments.