# Why should I set the __doc__ of a partial object in Python?

Tags: python, functools

[`help()` doesn't show the `__doc__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16672856/383793) of a partial object.
Yet, the example in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) sets it:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> basetwo = partial(int, base=2)
>>> basetwo.__doc__ = 'Convert base 2 string to an int.'
>>> basetwo('10010')
18
```

Why set `__doc__`, if it doesn't help?

Comment: Apparently, `pydoc` does not know about `partial` objects and does not expect them to have a doctoring. In theory, a smarter tool would.

Comment: Ran into the same.  I showed here how to rewrite `partial()` as a decorator factory that preserves `__doc__`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093057/534674

Comment: idk when this changed, but the example works fine in python 3.11. help(basetwo) does show the docstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected in python 3.11:

```py
>>> help(basetwo)
Help on partial in module functools:

functools.partial(<class 'int'>, base=2)
    Convert base 2 string to an int.
```

You might want to consider setting `__name__` as well:

```py
>>> basetwo.__name__ = "basetwo"
>>> help(basetwo)
Help on partial in module functools:

basetwo = functools.partial(<class 'int'>, base=2)
    Convert base 2 string to an int.
```

Or be even more complete:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093057/383793

Answer (score 0):

setting `__doc__` for a partial function is the same as doing this for a larger function:

```
def somefunc(somerandomarg):
    """This is a docstring
    What I am doing is shorthand for __doc__ = "random docstring"
    For partials, you can't do this, so you set it with __doc__"""
    pass
```

It's always good to document anything, even partials.

Comment: I expected them to be the same too. But if you read the `help()` question I linked, you'll see, that they aren't the same; a partial isn't a function, but an object. `help()` will show the __doc__ of the partial class and its methods.

Comment: As it said in the link, you can't override that without messing with the Python code. In Python, though, pydoc will show the docstring when you type it in.

Comment: What do you mean by type it in? When I type this in a part.py and `pydoc part.basetwo` shows the __doc__ of partial, not the __doc__ I typed in.

Comment: Go into Python Shell, and define a partial function basetwo like in the docs. Then type in `basetwo(`. Your doc will show up. I think the reason help doesn't work is that no one coded pydoc to appreciate the functional nature of partial objects. However, both accessing the direct `basetwo.__doc__` and typing `basetwo(` will work, so for some things setting `__doc__` actually helps.